# Laravel Forge- No such file directory in Edit Nginx Configuration

Tags: laravel, deployment, nginx-config, forge

I am new to Laravel Forge and l want to deploy my app with laravel at backend.
What should l type in the following fields so that my app can be deployed successfully:
Deploy Script and
Edit nginx configuration under Edit Files

I tried to restart the server and nginx file but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of Laravel Forge is that you do not need to type anything in there.

Deploy Script is already there when you create new app on server.
Nginx configuration is also there so there is no need to do anything with it.

Maybe you wondering how to create new laravel app on forge? if that is the case then you need to create your local app first on your computer then you need to do your first commit to github and then you need to deploy that repositiry to your Laravel Forge.

Watch this tutorial it will explain in in detail: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-forge-2022-edition/

Comment: l deployed an app from my GitHub repository but to my surprise, there is no content in the Nginx Configuration except this statement:
cat: '/etc/nginx/sites-available/http://app.example.co.za': No such file or directory

Comment: l deleted the app l was deploying and recreated a new site .lt was successfully deployed. Thanks @aurawindsurfing